# Trouble with unsupervised clustering method of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I'm working on some Python ML exercises and I'm stuck on a question.
I have a dataframe with 7 columns and almost 10k lines. 6 of those column/variables are objects and 1 is a float. The 7 variables are : Company, Job, Technologies, Degree, Experience (the one float variable - # of years), City, and Exp_level.

I want to do an unsupervised clustering to show 2 variables I deem important.

The code I've been testing hasn't been working and it seems that there is an issue with the mixed variables I have.

```
    x = df
    y = x.pop('Metier')

    y.unique()

    OneHotEncoder().fit(df.dropna()).categories_

    x.values, y

    for weights in ['uniform', 'distance']:
    # we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
    clf = KNN.KNeighborsClassifier(5, weights=weights)
    
    clf.fit(x.values, y.values)

    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    plt.figure()
    plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)

    # Plot also the training points
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=cmap_bold,
                edgecolor='k', s=20)
    plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    plt.title("3-Class classification (k = %i, weights = '%s')"
              % (n_neighbors, weights))

plt.show()
```

This is the 8th exercise by the way, so all my imports and dataframe loading were done in the beginning.

The error I keep having is `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Sanofi'` (the name of a company).

I'm doing my best to train and work on my Python skills. I hope I gave enough information to show that. Is there a better way to obtain my goal? I can only use the libraries :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import sklearn as sk
import sklearn.neighbors as KNN
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import seaborn as sb
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Hoping I can figure out this tricky exercise, any help would be greatly appreciated! I thank you in advance :) Super happy to be working on my Python skills more and more.

This is my df : [image]

Comment: You seem to have textual data which you need to convert to numbers with the help of onehotencoder, countvectorizer, or tfidfvectorizer

Comment: On my 4th line, I tried using onehotencoder... is there a better way of implementing it?

Comment: 1. You need to separate floats and strings 2. do a `fit_transform()` on textual data 3. Assign it to a new variable